# Can somebody explain dbms_sql.number_table

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I tried to search this but could not get a satisfactory answer hence posting here . somebody please explain

Comment: Sorry but what are you asking? Googling that term (the very FIRST link) gives an entire page of information?  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#CHDFDCDE --- this might also help (if it doesn't make sense, then time to hit the books) "Oracle lets you write stored procedures and anonymous PL/SQL blocks that use dynamic SQL. Dynamic SQL statements are not embedded in your source program; rather, they are stored in character strings that are input to, or built by, the program at runtime. This enables you to create more general-purpose procedures."

Comment: @robnick all I need a lucid and nice example . :)

Comment: @AsfakulIslam - Do you understand the basics of PL/SQL collections?  `dbms_sql.number_table` is just a collection that happens to be defined in the `dbms_sql` package.  It's no different from a collection that you could declare in your own package.

Comment: @JustinCave Is it only for holding numbers?

Comment: @AsfakulIslam - Yes, it is a collection of numbers.  More specifically, an associative array of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to understand `DBMS_SQL` itself to some extent, before understanding `NUMBER_TABLE`.

( I do this for *My* Learning!)

```
NUMBER_TABLE
```

is Actually,

```
TYPE number_table IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

So, only numbers are allowed!

**FlowChart on How DBMS_SQL Works! :**

Your interested area comes in *bind variable* box

---

```
--                    | open_cursor |
--                      -----------
--                           |
--                           |
--                           v
--                         -----
--          ------------>| parse |
--          |              -----
--          |                |
--          |                | ---------
--          |                v          |
--          |           --------------  |
--          |-------->| bind_variable | |
--          |     ^     -------------   |
--          |     |           |         |
--          |      -----------|         |
--          |                 |<--------
--          |                 v
--          |               query?---------- yes ---------
--          |                 |                           |
--          |                no                           |
--          |                 |                           |
--          |                 v                           v
--          |              -------                  -------------
--          |----------->| execute |            ->| define_column |
--          |              -------             |    -------------
--          |                 |------------    |          |
--          |                 |            |    ----------|
--          |                 v            |              v
--          |           --------------     |           -------
--          |       ->| variable_value |   |  ------>| execute |
--          |      |    --------------     | |         -------
--          |      |          |            | |            |
--          |       ----------|            | |            |
--          |                 |            | |            v
--          |                 |            | |        ----------
--          |                 |<-----------  |----->| fetch_rows |
--          |                 |              |        ----------
--          |                 |              |            |
--          |                 |              |            v
--          |                 |              |  -----------------
--          |                 |              | | column_value    |
--          |                 |              | | variable_value  |
--          |                 |              |  -----------------
--          |                 |              |            |
--          |                 |<--------------------------
--          |                 |
--           -----------------|
--                            |
--                            v
--                       ------------
--                     | close_cursor |
--      

             ------------
```

**Example:**
In a `DELETE` statement, for example, you could bind in an array in the `WHERE` clause and have the statement be run for each element in the array:

```
DECLARE
  stmt VARCHAR2(200);
  dept_no_array DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE;
  c NUMBER;
  dummy NUMBER;
begin
  dept_no_array(1) := 10; dept_no_array(2) := 20; /* Put some values into the array */
  dept_no_array(3) := 30; dept_no_array(4) := 40;
  dept_no_array(5) := 30; dept_no_array(6) := 40;
  stmt := 'delete from emp where deptno = :dept_array'; /* A Dynamic SQL String with a bind variable */
  c := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR; /* Open a Cursor! */
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(c, stmt, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE); /* Parse the Dynamic SQL , making it happen on the native database to which is connected! */

  DBMS_SQL.BIND_ARRAY(c, ':dept_array', dept_no_array, 1, 4);
  /* Bind only elements 1 through 4 to the cursor Happens 4 times */

  dummy := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(c);
  /* Execute the Query, and return number of rows deleted! */

  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c); 

  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF DBMS_SQL.IS_OPEN(c) THEN
      DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c);
    END IF;
    RAISE;
END;
/
```

**P.S.** Pure *rip-off*, with some more commments ,from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10577/d_sql.htm)