# Do a IN in stored procedure with variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm developing a stored procedure and i'm stuck in a step.
In some point i have this:

```
stmt := stmt || ' AND Risk.Code IN (:4) ';
```

How can i make risk.code do a in when :4 is a text variable that contains the list of values
"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20"

Comment: bind variables are not applicable for `IN` clause this way. It should be like `IN (:1,:2,:3)`. You can insert these values into a nestd tables, and `CAST` it as a table. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695220/oracle-dynamic-query-with-in-clause-using-cursor/21695311#21695311). You can also try out [NUMBER_TABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10577/d_sql.htm) - along with `DBMS_SQL` as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335493/can-somebody-explain-dbms-sql-number-table/21336827#21336827)

Comment: Tom Kyte has documented an approach to this type of problem, http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2006/06/varying-in-lists.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it,

```
stmt := stmt || ' AND Risk.Code IN ('|| P_RISK ||') ';
```

Comment: That is risky because of SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert comma separated values into an varray and then use

`stmt := stmt || ' AND Risk.Code IN (select column_value
from TABLE(v_my_data))';`

One technique: https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement